# As a system admin, I'm unable to query custom fields I create on the lineItemSchedule object

Tags: opp-lineitemschedule, opportunitylineitemschedule

Executing queries via SOQL.

I am able to query custom fields on other objects in the org.

However, I noticed I am not able to run queries on custom fields created on the lineItemSchedule object.

Not sure if this is relevant info: In the Product Schedule settings in Setup the "Enable Customization of Product Schedules (Lightning Experience Only)" is checked, but greyed out.

Why am I not able to query any custom fields on the lineItemSchedule object?

Comment: The permissions might be missing from your profile. Please create a Permission Set and add the relevant custom field permissions through it.

Comment: Thank you @Hariprasath - the profile itself had not granted permission to those fields even as a system admin.